# Conditional tags in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, conditional-statements

Sorry for the trivial question but I'm not very skilled in php...
I need to display a slideshow on every page of my wordpress site except in one (sponsor).
I tried with this code but does not work.

```
<? php if (! is_sponsor ()) {do_action ('slideshow_deploy', '3484'); }?>
```

Where did I go wrong?

The normal code to display the slideshow is:

```
<?php do_action('slideshow_deploy', '3484'); ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the `is_sponsor` fundtion do? If it's working correctly, then the code you posted would work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think there's no such function, I just tried it. Is there a conditional tag that makes sure to don't display it on a single page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the slider on the page with slug "sponsor", try with the following code:

```
if( !is_page('sponsor') ) {
    do_action('slideshow_deploy', '3484');
}
```

If you want to disable the slider on posts from post type "sponsor", try with the following code:

```
if( !( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'sponsor' ) ) {
    do_action('slideshow_deploy', '3484');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
It was exactly what I was looking for.
It works great!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `is_sponsor`

to not display it for that single page

create a new page template and completely remove

`<?php do_action('slideshow_deploy', '3484'); ?>`

here is the naming structure

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I entered that code in the footer then displays the slideshow on every page of the site. I have not put it in page.php.
Is there a conditional tag that makes sure to don't display it on a single page?

Comment: no conditional tags needed make a page.php template file named `yourpageslughere-page.php` and your different template will be used for that single page.